# Adding data to a selection

Tags: d3.js

I have trouble to add paths to a g element created by the nodes with selectAll:

```
// define the nodes
var node = svg.selectAll(".node").data(force.nodes()).enter()
        .append("g").attr("id", function(d) {
            return d.id;
        }).attr("class", "node").style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.group);
        }).call(force.drag);

// add the nodes
...

// add the links and the arrows
var path = node.selectAll("g").data(force.links(), function(d) {
    return d.id
}).append("path")
//    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
.attr("class", "link").attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
```

The input data looks like this:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "N1",
      "group": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "N2",
      "group": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "N3",
      "group": 1
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "source": 0,
      "target": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 0,
      "source": 0,
      "target": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to modify [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/7830074)

My goal is that a node has a mouse over (.node:hover) including all the out-going links. With my simple data it would look like that node N1 would have a mouse over including the two links.

Thanks for your help!

Here is all the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<style>
.node {
    opacity: 0.8;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
    pointer-events: none;
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    stroke-width: 0px;
}

.node:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

path.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #666;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <script>
        // get the data
        d3.json("data2.json", function(error, graph) {

            var color = d3.scale.category20();
            var width = 960, height = 500;

            var force = d3.layout.force().nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links)
                    .size([ width, height ]).linkDistance(300).charge(-300).on(
                            "tick", tick).start();

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height);

            // build the arrow.
            svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker").data([ "end" ]) // Different link/path types can be defined here
            .enter().append("svg:marker") // This section adds in the arrows
            .attr("id", String).attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10").attr("refX", 15)
                    .attr("refY", -1.5).attr("markerWidth", 6).attr(
                            "markerHeight", 6).attr("orient", "auto").append(
                            "svg:path").attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

            // define the nodes
            var node = svg.selectAll(".node").data(force.nodes()).enter()
                    .append("g").attr("id", function(d) {
                        return d.id;
                    }).attr("class", "node").style("fill", function(d) {
                        return color(d.group);
                    }).call(force.drag);

            // add the nodes
            node.append("circle").attr("r", function(d) {
                return 3 * d.group
            });

            // add the text 
            node.append("text").attr("x", 12).attr("dy", ".35em").style(
                    "color", "black").text(function(d) {
                return d.name;
            });

            // add the links and the arrows
            var path = node.selectAll("g").data(force.links(), function(d) {
                return d.id
            }).append("path")
            //    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
            .attr("class", "link").attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

            // add the curvy lines
            function tick() {
                path.attr("d", function(d) {
                    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x, dy = d.target.y
                            - d.source.y, dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + ","
                            + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
                });

                node.attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                });
            }

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what question you are asking.  What is happening that you don't want to happen?  What is not happening that you do want to happen?  (I probably won't be able to answer the question--I don't know enough--but I think that clarifying the question will help those people who can answer it.)

Comment: I want to append all out-going links to its nodes. In the svg: the path needs to be in the g element. g holds the circle (node) and the text. If everything is in the g, I can add a css-node:hover

Comment: I'm a d3 newbie, and don't understand the code fully, but here's a thought I had. Doesn't `selectAll("g").data(force.links()...)` create one new empty `g` element for every link?  Or rather, it would if you added `.enter()` after that expression.  Do you need something like `.selectAll("g").selectAll("link").data(force.links(),...).enter().append(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue with mouseover and mouseout:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="author" content="myborobudur">
      <meta name="date" content="2014-09-02T00:00:00+01:00">
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Job Recommender: d3js Graph Study</title>
      <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
      <style>
         .node {
         opacity: 0.8;
         stroke: #fff;
         stroke-width: 1.5px;
         }
         .text {
         pointer-events: none;
         font: 12px sans-serif;
         stroke-width: 0px;
         color: #000;
         }
         .node:hover {
         opacity: 1;
         }
         path.link {
         fill: none;
         stroke: #666;
         stroke-width: 1.5px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>Job Recommender: d3js Graph Study</h2>
      <script>
         function selectLinks(thisObject) {
            changeLinkStyle(thisObject, function(node, link) {
                link.style("stroke", node.attr("fillColor"));
                link.style("stroke-width", "10px");
                link.style("opacity", "0.5");
                link.attr("marker-end", "");
            });
         }

         function deSelectLinks(thisObject) {
            changeLinkStyle(thisObject, function(node, link) {
                link.style("stroke", "#666");
                link.style("stroke-width", "1.5px");
                link.style("opacity", "1");
                link.attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
            });
         }

         function changeLinkStyle(thisObject, changeStyle) {
            var source = d3.select(thisObject);
            var sourceId = d3.select(thisObject).attr('id');
            d3.selectAll('.link').each(function(d, i) {
                var link = d3.select(this);
                var linkSourceId = link.attr('source');
                if (linkSourceId === sourceId) {
                    changeStyle.call(undefined, source, link);
                }
            });
         }

         // get the data
         d3.json("data.json", function(error, graph) {

            var color = d3.scale.category20();
            var width = 1200, height = 800;

            var force = d3.layout.force().nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links)
                            .size([ width, height ])
                            .linkDistance(300)
                            .charge(-300)
                            .on("tick", tick)
                            .start();

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                            .attr("width", width)
                            .attr("height", height);

            // build the arrow.
            svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
                            .data([ "end" ]) // Different link/path types can be defined here
                            .enter().append("svg:marker") // This section adds in the arrows
                            .attr("id", String)
                            .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
                            .attr("refX", 15)
                            .attr("refY", -1.5)
                            .attr("markerWidth", 6)
                            .attr("markerHeight", 6)
                            .attr("orient", "auto")
                            .append("svg:path")
                            .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

            // add the links and the arrows
            var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
                            .data(force.links())
                            .enter().append("svg:path")                 
                            .attr("class", "link")
                            .attr("source", function(d) { return d.source.id })
                            .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

            // define the nodes
            var node = svg.selectAll(".node").data(force.nodes())
                            .enter().append("g").call(force.drag);

            // add the nodes
            node.append("circle").attr("id", function(d) { return d.id })
                            .attr("fillColor", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
                            .attr("onmouseover", "selectLinks(this)")
                            .attr("onmouseout", "deSelectLinks(this)")
                            .attr("class", "node")
                            .attr("r", function(d) { return 3 * d.group })
                            .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); });

            // add the text 
            node.append("text").attr("x", 12)
                            .attr("dy", ".35em")
                            .attr("class", "text")
                            .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

            // add the curvy lines
            function tick() {
                path.attr("d", function(d) {
                    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x, dy = d.target.y - d.source.y, dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
                });

                node.attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                });
            }

         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```